# Why can't I get my app to stay on my device?

Tags: android, flutter

I have a device plugged in which I test my app on.

How do I make it install on the phone and stay there even without my development environment running. Is this possible or do I have to publish the app or something similar. Thanks.

Comment: What about `flutter install`?

Comment: what is your "development environment "

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yep that worked. I had to CD into the root of my project directy and run `flutter install` - thanks

Comment: Of course, otherwise the `flutter` tool wouldn't know what project you want to build and install.

Answer (score 2):

Run

```
flutter install
```

in the project root directory.